# iOS unable to receive notification, suspected to be GCM

Tags: ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have a production iOS apps that are running perfectly and able receive notification. im attempting to create another application, the difference is changing only the application name and logos/image. Other than that it's almost identical to the 2nd application.

Unfortunately the server returned GCM "ERROR : NOT REGISTERED" as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXDeo.png

Things i've done :

- Requested new certSigningRequestFile
- Added new p12 file onto the server
- configured ios push notification in apple developer portal
- created new provisioning profile.

The application still cannot receive notification as the first application.

Did i miss anything ?

Comment: Did you register and receive a new token through the new app? Also did you include the appropriate configuration file?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. do you mind to elaborate more on the token part ?

Comment: I guess what he meant was if you're using the GCM Library with the proper configuration parameters to get GCM registration token for your app. Also are your valid certs installed on GCM?